# Why can't I see HttpUtility.ParseQueryString Method?

Tags: http, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am developing a simple app to consume a web API using this new fantastic .Net core framework. In one of my previous projects I use HttpUtility.ParseQueryString to parse the query string. But I couldn't find any reference to this method in new Asp.Net core RC2 assemblies and packages. It may happen that there is new method available which I don't know yet. I my current project, I have referenced following packages-

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.WebApiCompatShim": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.0.0-rc2-3002702",
      "type": "platform"
    },
    "System.Collections.Specialized": "4.0.1-rc2-24027",
    "System.Net.Http": "4.0.1-rc2-24027",
    "System.Runtime.Serialization.Json": "4.0.1"
```

Is there any other package that I need to reference in order to access this Method?

Comment: Thanks Tom, that is helpful

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> ASP.NET Core has a number of architectural changes that result in a much leaner and modular framework. ASP.NET Core is no longer based on System.Web.dll. It is based on a set of granular and well factored NuGet packages. ([Introduction to ASP.NET Core](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/intro.html#why-build-asp-net-core))

Now you can find it in the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities` assembly with the signature: [Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.QueryHelpers.ParseQuery](https://docs.asp.net/projects/api/en/latest/autoapi/Microsoft/AspNetCore/WebUtilities/QueryHelpers/#meth-Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.QueryHelpers.ParseQuery)

Comment: Documentation was moved to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.webutilities.queryhelpers#Microsoft_AspNetCore_WebUtilities_QueryHelpers_ParseQuery_System_String_